# Static webpage automatically zooming on Safari

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

When I load my static HTML webpage on safari, the browser is automatically zooming in so that my users get a horizontal scrollbar. I'm not getting this issue on any other browser and device. I've ensured all text on the site is 16px or greater and have set the metatags to the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1">
```

Let me know if there is anything I may not be considering or an approach I should be taking to debug this.

Comment: Please provide feedback if this question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being caused by an inline width attribute on an image that was causing an overflow for portrait view.

```
<img src="/img/text-logo-white.svg", width=400>
```

Removing the width solved the issue.